# Keep website url constant when navigating to another page?

Tags: .htaccess, url, browser

I want my site address bar not to change its address when I go to subpages, it should show my `index.html`, even though I enter tosub pages.

Like if I open `www.xyz.com` and I navigate to any page it should still show `www.xyz.com`.

I heard this can be done with `.htaccess` is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want this? Do you want to annoy your users and sabotage search engines? Users like to be able to bookmark pages.

Comment: i saw on one website.. so just want to know how to do that

Comment: We'll explain how to do it, and we'll also explain why not to do it. You shouldn't implement stuff "just because it looks cool" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should think about why you want it, because this way of working has a couple of drawbacks with it:

- Users can't see they are on a different page
- Users can't bookmark your pages for fast access
- Users can't share links to eachother
- Search Engines may have trouble spidering your side

But basically, there are two main ways to do this:

1. Use frames. Put the page into a frame, and have all the links stay in this frame.
2. Use Javascript. Have each page "load" into the current page, using AJAX.

Comment: As long as you stick to this advice and don't actually implement it, it's a good answer. If you do we'll find you and beat you to the head with an iframe, mr_eclair.