# Maintain the same URL throughout the website

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I want to have a same URL throughout my website. Whatever the user clicks on the web page, the redirected link should not display in the address bar in order to avoid the user to bookmark that page.

Whatever it is, the user have to come from the home page and should follow the link to proceed further.

Any help???

Comment: Why would that even make sense? Basically what you are trying to do is  breaking default behaviour that users are accustomed to. No good idea, if you ask me.

Comment: You can wrap your website with a `frameset`.

Comment: If you really want to break your website like this you could use framesets (or iframes) or Ajax. Though I agree with @losfinkos

Comment: @losfinkos There are certain circumstances where it is important a user cannot jump to a particular page.  I would actually suggest creating an ajax based page that loads the main section of the page based on parameters you pass the ajax call.

Comment: Using Ajax could do the trick. But still you need to be aware that you are not only preventing bookmarking but you are also breaking the browser's Back-button.

Comment: already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216907/keep-website-url-constant-when-nagivating-to-another-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly possible!
As stated before, this is achievable using Silverlight/flash/..
but also with HTML.

You can take a look at MVC4 SPA (single-page-application)
MVC4 provides a lot of tools which come in handy.

I personally did it with Java.

The main idea is.. you handly all the logic using javascript. So when a user clicks a link, you fetch the html using AJAX and swap the current html with the updated one.

Please note (just like flash and silverlight) this is a SEO-killer ...

Comment: Looks like you can also use GWT.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options-

1. build your site with flash / silverlight or something like that.
2. put all your site in a IFrame, and navigate through it.
3. put a single http endpoint and put all your data in the http request data (with an post body or a session or cookie).

for 2 and 3 users might sniff the traffic and jump to specific page.

but can you please explain more on why you need it? I don't it's really what you want to do.

Comment: All new users have to go from the home page to other page so that their credentials gets stored..if they automatically jump to some other pages the creadentials are not getting saved so. it was requested by the admin and i have to do that. i have explained them telling that the back button wont work in that case but they are not bothered.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with HTML only unless you use IFrames but your are not going to get far.

'Single URL' web sites use javascript XMLHttpRequest/Ajax calls or frameworks like Flash, Siverlight, etc...

All Javascript frameworks (Dojo, jQuery, Ext Js, etc...) offer ways of injecting HTML residing in multiple files into the current page if you have to restart from an existing collection of HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea may render google robots (and others) unable to index your site properly ...

Anyway you just have to replace all GET requests (links) by POST requests (forms).

Example :

```
<a href="?do=foo&var=bar">click here</a>
```

should be replaced by

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="foo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="bar" />
    <input type="submit" name="click" value="click here" />
</form>
```